# Swift Library with Objective-C and C++

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c++

I am writting a Swift framework wrapper for the C++ Library *Clipper*. The wrapper can be found [here](https://github.com/rusty1s/RSClipperWrapper). In my example project, everything just works fine. You can download and compile and see, that it works.

But when I try to install this wrapper as a cocoapod, I get the error

```
'vector' file not found
Could not build Objective-C module 'RSClipperWrapper'
```

pointing to `clipper.hpp`. All problems like this seem to have a problem with `.mm`-files or compiler settings. I think this is not the case here. It's strange that XCode complains about an Objective-C module when in reality, its an Swift module. Is CocoaPods not yet ready for such tasks?

I am at my wit's end. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my problem. I had to add a `private_header_files` section in my podspec, so that the `*.hpp` files are private.